# return value from a event-binded function

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I'm trying to write a function which can wait for me to press anykey and then return my mouse position. I'm confused about how to get my xy value from key(event) function and return them with get_mouse_pixel().

```
from Tkinter import *
import win32api

def get_mouse_pixel():
    x,y = 0,0

    root = Tk()

    def key(event):
        x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        print "pressed", repr(event.char)
        print "mouse position", x, y
        root.quit()

    def callback(event):
        print "clicked at", event.x, event.y

    frame = Frame(root, width=0, height=0)
    frame.bind("<Key>", key)
    frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
    frame.pack()
    frame.focus_set()

    root.mainloop()

print x,y
return x,y

get_mouse_pixel()
```

Comment: You get x and y in key() but never call it. And it's not a good practice to define functions inside functions.

Comment: @Alex.S why is it not a good practice to define functions inside functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using inner functions and you give them values, you have to tell your inner function (`key()`) that the `x` and `y` you're setting aren't new variables, they're the ones in the outer scope. You can do that with the `nonlocal` keyword in python3 (eg `nonlocal x,y` `x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()`), or `global` in python2. If you didn't assign to them, you could read from them in the inner scope, but you can't re-assign to them.

A different way to do it is that you *can* modify nonlocal variables. I.e. you can change mutable data types that aren't local- if you change `x` and `y` into a dictionary `d = {'x':0, 'y':0}`, your `key()` can change that nonlocal;

```
# Define x/y as dictionary d higher
def key(event):
    d['x'],d['y'] = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    # Everything else you would like to do with x/y.
```

This will change dictionary `d` to hold the new values without having to do potentially destructive things with global variables with the immensely common names `x` and `y`.

With the dict method, you can either return the whole dictionary or you can return each piece (ie `return d['x'], d['y']`) to return nice ints if you want.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the keyword global and it works. Will this global declaration affect anything else if I'm going to call the get_mouse_pixel() function multiple times in other program?

Comment: @Siyu If any variable in your other program is named `x` or `y`, it may clash and cause weird bugs that may be hard to track down. I heavily recommend using the dictionary method, as it allows for more tied encapsulation (or swapping into python 3 so you can use `nonlocal` since it is bounded better.)